# How to query an elasticsearch aggregation with a term and sum on different nested objects?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nested, aggregate

I have the following object whose `value` attribute is a nested object type:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "tenant": "home",
        "timestamp": "2016-03-24T23:59:38Z"
    },
    "value": {
        { "key": "foo", "int_value": 100 },
        { "key": "bar", "str_value": "taco" }
    }
}
```

This type of object has the following mapping:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "my_doctype": {
                "properties": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "properties": {
                            "tenant": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "timestamp": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "str_value": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "int_value": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "key": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, I would like to perform an aggregation that performs the following result:

- Perform a `term` aggregation on the `str_value` attribute of objects where the `key` is set to `"bar"`
- In each bucket created from the above aggregation, calculate the `sum` of the `int_value` attributes where the `key` is set to `"foo"`
- Have the results laid out in a `date_histogram` for a given time range.

With this goal in mind, I have been able to get the `term` and `date_histogram` aggregations to work on my nested objects, but have not had luck performing the second level of calculation. Here is the current query I am attempting to get working:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filters": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "metadata.org": "gw"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "metadata.timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2016-03-24T23:59:59.999Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "intervals": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "metadata.timestamp",
            "interval": "1d",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": "2016-03-24T00:00:00Z",
              "max": "2016-03-24T23:59:59Z"
            },
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nested_type": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "value"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "key_filter": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "value.key": "bar"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "groupBy": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "value.str_value"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "other_nested": {
                          "reverse_nested": {
                            "path": "value"
                          },
                          "aggs": {
                            "key_filter": {
                              "filter": {
                                "term": {
                                  "value.key": "foo"
                                }
                              },
                              "aggs": {
                                "amount_sum": {
                                  "sum": {
                                    "field": "value.int_value"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I am **expecting** to receive from Elasticsearch would look like the following:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "filters": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "intervals": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key_as_string": "2016-03-24T00:00:00Z",
            "key": 1458777600000,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "nested_type": {
              "doc_count": 5,
              "key_filter": {
                "doc_count": 2,
                "groupBy": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "taco",
                      "doc_count": 1,
                      "other_nested": {
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "key_filter": {
                          "doc_count": 1,
                          "amount_sum": {
                            "value": 100.0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the innermost object (`...groupBy.buckets.key_filter.amount_sum`) is having its `value` return `0.0` instead of `100.0`.

I think this is due to the fact that nested objects are indexed as separate documents, so filtering by one `key` attribute's value is not allowing me to query to against another `key`.

Would anyone have any idea on how to get this type of query to work?

For a bit more context, the reason for this document structure is because I do not control the content of the JSON documents that get indexed, so different `tenant`s may have conflicting key names with different values (e.g. `{"tenant": "abc", "value": {"foo": "a"} }` vs. `{"tenant": "xyz", "value": {"foo": 1} }`. The method I am trying to use is the one laid out by this [Elasticsearch Blog Post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring), where it recommends to transform objects that you don't control into a structure that you do and to use nested objects to help with this (specifically the `Nested fields for each data type` section of the article). I would also be open to learn of a better way to handle this situation of not controlling the document's JSON structure if there is one so that I can perform aggregations.

Thank you!

EDIT: I am using Elasticsearch 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this situation by utilizing the `reverse_nested` aggregation in the correct way as described here: http://www.shayne.me/blog/2015/2015-05-18-elasticsearch-nested-docs/